# Why my android studio web view app goes blank white after splash screen in signed release and works perfect id debug?

Tags: android, android-studio

Some how it works on older devices but i tried in 2 new devices the release app doesnt work its shows a white blank screeen after splash screen

And there is no error showing please answer me

main activity

```
    private WebView mywebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();

        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mywebview.loadUrl("https://netixshop.com/");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }




    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
        }else{
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }

        }
    }
```

here is my manifest
pleasse check this out and find why is the error caused

android manifest

````
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".splashactivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't add the internet permission to Manifest file while it is added to debug manifest file by default. So you need to add the internet permission;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and if you work with android 8 or above, probably you will need to add this line under `application` tag for accessing to non-https web urls;

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

finally it will look like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes i did both earlier itself still no use.....when i installed the signed version only theproblem occurs